# Wordpress javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've dealt with WP js conflicts before, but this one has me stumped.  I have a simple form with four questions.  The user must click yes on all for the link to show up.  I've been able to recreate this with only jquery 1.6.2 on a single pg on a test server, so I know the js and the form work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        if(
            ($('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
            ($('input:radio[name=group2]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
            ($('input:radio[name=group3]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
            ($('input:radio[name=group4]:checked').val() == 'Yes')
        ){
            document.getElementById('pdflink').innerHTML = '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('pdflink').innerHTML = '';
        }

    });
});
</script>

<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<div><br>
<p>Question 1?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 2?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 3?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 4?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"> No<br>
</div>
</form>
<div id="pdflink">
</div>
```

Here's the link: http://www.hcfmissoula.com/grants/compassionate-care-grant

I've tried using the jQuery.noConflict approach with no luck.  Please help if you can...

Comment: @Matt Ball, have you opened the link?  I does not do what it's supposed to do.  The link does not show.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - I interpreted your description of the desired behavior as the description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@blackessej, your code is not making it to the client side.  This is what I see in my browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        if(
            ($('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &#038;&#038;
            ($('input:radio[name=group2]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &#038;&#038;
            ($('input:radio[name=group3]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &#038;&#038;
            ($('input:radio[name=group4]:checked').val() == 'Yes')
        ){
        document.getElementById('pdflink').innerHTML = '
<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>
<p>';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('pdflink').innerHTML = '';
        }</p>
    <p>    });
});
```

The && operators are getting escaped and there are random <p> tags in your script.

Comment: yes, and thanks for pointing this out before (sorry I didn't respond).  What do you think is causing this?  Those are just the HTML numbers for the ampersand symbol.  I've tried disabling all plugins...

Comment: Can you toss it in an external .js file?

Comment: something to do with the HTML editor in WP.  Maybe the theme has a conflict, but when I put the js in `header.php`, the problem went away.  Thanks for your help.